# How to get any datetime in microseconds from any date in php

Tags: php, microtime

i'm wondering if there's a way to get any datetime in microseconds.

I was looking forward microtime(), but it just returns the date in the moment.

Anyone knows if is this possible?

I have my date given like: `Y-m-d H:i:s.u.`

I was thinking about something like `(Y-1970)*31556926 + m*151200+d*86400+h*3600+m*60+s.u`

but I don't know if that's why i'm a beginner on programming, but i can't think in a way to separate each: Y,m... to do the math.

Would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: So are you looking for a timestamp then . microseconds? Like this `1335939007.654321`?

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm looking for, but for any date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `DateTime`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '2000-01-01 13:12:12.129817');
echo $date->format('U.u');
//prints: 946728732.129817
```

Comment: DateTime does not support fractional seconds, so I believe the fractional component would be lost with this approach.  You could use this to get the whole second value though.

Comment: I thought that was the case but I just tested it and it worked correctly.

Comment: Really?  That is interesting. The documentation commentary would seem to suggest otherwise. Maybe this is now supported. If that is the case, then yet another reason why DateTime and DateInterval should be THE date/time tools of choice for PHP developers.

Comment: If you get the chance please test also I am running php5.5 I would be interested to see if it isn't supported in earlier versions.

Comment: must be a really new feature : http://3v4l.org/TC0Ck ;) it is not working, it gives u always `0000`

Comment: I tested multiple versions of PHP on here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cc3406840b0065eeb7f268cd5958b41e2ea92fc seemed to work correctly in each.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't output the current time. Use `microtime()` as I suggested.

Comment: OP doesn't want current time, he already has it, he just wants to change formatting. At least that is what I understand from OP. "I have my date given like: Y-m-d H:i:s.u."

Comment: Seems to work in 5.3.1 and above http://3v4l.org/P3n6v if you aren't running that new of a version I recommend going with Mike Brant's answer.

Comment: The question was hard to get, especially after the comments below my answer. I thought he needs the current time in usec.. however, now all are happy...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is simply split apart your input format like this:

`Y-m-d H:i:s` and `u`

You should be able to do this by exploding on `.` in your input formatted date string.  Then just calculate the UNIX timestamp on the whole second portion.  Finally just add your fraction second portion back to the timestamp (via either string concatenation of arithmetic depending on whether you want string or float as result).

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Timestamps are integers internally, describing the seconds from 01.01.1970 GMT. Regardless if you are using a 32 or 64 bit system, the microseconds from 1970 would lead to an overflow as there has much too many of them gone.

---

You updated the question.. Yes, it is possible to display the current time in microsends using `microtime()`:

```
$microtime = microtime();
// will return something like:
// 0.40823900 1381181037
// where the first are the micros and the last a regular time stamp
list($micros, $timestamp) = explode(' ', $microtime);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', intval($timestamp)) . '+' 
  . (floatval($micros) * 1000000) . 'msec';
```

Comment: Hmm, i see the part of integers. But, how could they lead to an overflow if the microtime works?

Comment: i don't know if i need to state it maybe, but, any date not so far from today. :)

Comment: first, microtime gives you a string, not a number. secondly, as you said, microtime gives you the current time in microseconds and not the microseconds from 1970

Comment: @GustavoxD Microtime uses string format (by default) or a float (if you pass true to its argument), both of which work okay for thejob.

Comment: Hm, i think i didn't mean what i want well, i want any date time in microseconds, if possible. Like a "microtime() for any date". I'll edit

Comment: It is possible. will give an example

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just picked the Pitchinnate's answer, cause it's easier and runned here.